# How to add a new member to an initialized expression tree?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am building an expression for a .Select call, it goes as follows

My model:

```
public class EmpFull
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The view model:

```
public class Emp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

And the expression:

```
Expression<Func<EmpFull, Emp>> expression = t => new Emp
{
    Id = t.Id,
    Name = t.Name
};
```

I want to do the following:

```
if (WithAddress)
{
    //Add the address to the expression tree
}
```

I have researched the expression tree methods and read the documentation but none of it helped me to understand it.

So, My question is: How can I add an extra parameter to the initialization expression?

Answer (score 3):

We start by looking at what expression we're actually dealing with.

If we inspect `expression.Body.GetType()`, we can see that it's a [`MemberInitExpression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.memberinitexpression?view=netframework-4.8). This consists of a [`NewExpression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.memberinitexpression.newexpression?view=netframework-4.8), which is the `new Emp` bit, and a number of [`Bindings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.memberinitexpression.bindings?view=netframework-4.8), which are the member initializers.

We're going to use an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.8) to rewrite this, as it's a bit cleaner than deconstructing / reconstructing it ourselves.

We're also going to follow the docs for [`Expression.MakeMemberInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.memberinit?view=netframework-4.8), which describes how to call [`Expression.Bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.bind?view=netframework-4.8).

Put it all together, and we end up with this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<EmpFull, Emp>> expression = t => new Emp
        {
            Id = t.Id,
            Name = t.Name
        };

        // Additional bindings to add to the MemberInit
        var additionalBindings = new[]
        {
            Expression.Bind(
                // Property to assign to
                typeof(Emp).GetMember("Address")[0],
                // Value to assign to it. We need to access the "Address" member
                // of 't' in the 'expression' variable above, which we'll
                // get from grabbing 'expression.Parameters[0]'
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                    expression.Parameters[0],
                    typeof(EmpFull).GetMember("Address")[0])),
        };
        var visitor = new AddNewBindingsVisitor(additionalBindings);
        var rewritten = visitor.Visit(expression);
    }
}
public class AddNewBindingsVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<MemberBinding> bindings;
    public AddNewBindingsVisitor(IEnumerable<MemberBinding> bindings) =>
        this.bindings = bindings;
    protected override Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node) =>
        node.Update(node.NewExpression, node.Bindings.Concat(bindings));
}
```

---

Now, this is quite ugly, but we can improve it. We'll create a method which takes two lambda expressions which take `MemberInitExpressions`, and we'll return something which contains a combination of all of those initializers.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<EmpFull, Emp>> expression = t => new Emp
        {
            Id = t.Id,
            Name = t.Name
        };

        Expression<Func<EmpFull, Emp>> additional = t => new Emp
        {
            Address = t.Address
        };

        var result = CombineInitializers(expression, additional);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<TSource, TNew>> CombineInitializers<TSource, TNew>
        (Expression<Func<TSource, TNew>> first, Expression<Func<TSource, TNew>> second)
    {
        if (!(first.Body is MemberInitExpression firstInit))
            throw new ArgumentException("Must contain a MemberInitExpression", nameof(first));
        if (!(second.Body is MemberInitExpression secondInit))
            throw new ArgumentException("Must contain a MemberInitExpression", nameof(second));

        var secondUsingFirstParameter = (MemberInitExpression)new ParameterReplaceVisitor(second.Parameters[0], first.Parameters[0]).Visit(secondInit);
        var combined = new AddNewBindingsVisitor(secondUsingFirstParameter.Bindings).Visit(firstInit);
        return first.Update(combined, first.Parameters);
    }
}

public class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression target;
    private readonly ParameterExpression replacement;
    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression target, ParameterExpression replacement) =>
        (this.target, this.replacement) = (target, replacement);
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) =>
        node == this.target ? this.replacement : base.VisitParameter(node);
}

public class AddNewBindingsVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<MemberBinding> bindings;
    public AddNewBindingsVisitor(IEnumerable<MemberBinding> bindings) =>
        this.bindings = bindings;
    protected override Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node) =>
        node.Update(node.NewExpression, node.Bindings.Concat(bindings));
}
```

This is a pretty straightforward extension of our previous usage of `AddNewBindingsVisitor`. The gotcha is that `first` and `second` have different parameter objects (that is, `t`), so we first need to rewrite one of them (`second`) to use the same parameter as the other (`first`). We do this using another visitor, which just replaces one `ParameterExpression` with another.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: @TarekMohamed Updated with a neater way of achieving the same thing